# How person in different gravity field be seen?

Tags: gravity, time

We know that gravity affects time. More the gravity, slower the time, and vice-versa.

Now consider a **hypothetical condition** where two people are walking next to each other. One person is subjected to a lot of gravity and the second person to a lot lesser.

How would first person see motion of second person? Since time would be running slower at first person's place and faster at second person's, would the first person see the second person to be moving faster than we usually see? Like a video is being fast forwarded?

Comment: yes, but for the effects to be noticeable the first person must be close to a very massive object, such as a black hole

Comment: @brucesmitherson yes, that's why I said consider a hypothetical condition

Comment: It actually isn't so hypothetical. Time runs slower when you go deeper in a gravity well. GPS works by a ground receiver determining how far it is from satellites. This is done by determining how long it takes a radio signal to travel from the satellite to the receiver. This depends on extremely accurate clocks. But clocks on satellites do not stay perfectly synchronized with clocks on earth. The receiver must correct. Things do run very slightly faster on the satellites.